# How to change global environment of python in m1 mac?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, homebrew, apple-m1

[image]
System monterey12.6.2, M1 macbook air.

I used homebrew and conda's miniforge to download two pythons. But now I start using jupyter in vscode, and I realized that the packages I usually install are in conda's environment, and the global environment of jupyter notebook kernel is set to the 3.9.16 installed by brew for some reason. And I found that the global env of jupyter kernel (which is 3.9.16) is different from the one in python interpreter (which is 3.10.9).
[image]
[image]

I have set miniforge's 3.9.15 in PATH and when I input python -V and python3 -V in terminal, they both show Python 3.9.15. But the global env in vsc still doesn't change.
Please give me some advice how to change this global env to 3.9.15 (installed by conda).

Comment: You have to select the interpreter for your VS Code project separately: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Comment: Thanks for comment. I'm sorry to omit that I'm using jupyter extension. I can choose python 3.9.15 as my jupyter kernel to use the packages I installed. But I'm curious that how can I change the global enviroment that displayed by vscode. And I found that the global env of jupyter kernel (which is 3.9.16) is different from the one in python interpreter (which is 3.10.9).